# While unit testing if an exception is being thrown, how can I know if the exception was thrown due to the error that I setted up?

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing

**TL;DR version**:

How should I known if my method is throwing an exception because of the error scenario that I configured and not because of another error? Also, should I always configure everything in order to test if an exception is being thrown, or only configuring what is used to the point where the exception is thrown is enough?

**Long version:**

I have a class, MyClass, which has a method called foo. The method foo calls an API that returns an object indicating if the operation succeded. If the object returned by the API indicates an error, the foo method should throw an unchecked exception.

In order to test if foo is throwing the exception, I'm mocking the API, so that it always indicates a fail. The foo method is working as expected, throwing an exception.

It is true, however, that other things can make foo throw exceptions. For instance, if the API succeds but other dependency of fool fails, fool will and should throw an excpetion.

Because of that, in order to test if foo is throwing an exception as results of a fail in the API, I need to mock every other dependency that foo has. Because of that, the unit test that tests if foo throws an exception when the API fails gets too big. This is also true for every other test involving exceptions.

The worst part is that, at the end of the day, I'm always questioning, is it throwing an exception because the API failed, or because there's another error happening?

The solution I can think is creating exception for every possible case of failure, like "HiImFooAndTheApiThatICalledFailed_Exception". I'm not sure if this is a reaonable approach though. Other solution is testing the exception's message, but I think this is bad because I would be limiting message to be static.

Comment: puh, much stuff. One thing you always have to ask yourself if your test gets complicated: Is my function doing too much?

Comment: @Klamsi while this is absolutely true, I have scenarios where, even though my function is doing little, it has more than one unexpected error scenarios, where it should throw an exception. So I would still need to test each scenario to verify if the function behaves as it should. So I think the question remains.

Comment: Ah ok. I use special exception classes if I want to be sure it's the right exception that is thrown.

Comment: @Klamsi cool. So like the "HiImFooAndTheApiThatICalledFailed_Exception" approach? Or you would try to make it more generic so it can be used by other classes too? If you have no problem with making it very specific, where would you put the class? In a folder that centralizes the exceptions of the layer/context, or together with the class that throws it?

Comment: Yes like that. But I would not overdo that concept. Do you relly care about the exeption class in all cases? If you for example say: wrong paremeters => exception; right parameters => OK and your module behaves like that it works as expected.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable. Thank you @Klamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock other dependency and check that no methods where called. So if you get exception you will be sure it is from your code.

If you code can throw exception in several different scenarios you test them all separately.

You don't need to worry about which piece of your code thrown exception, only that correct exception was thrown.

As long as you have test for all scenarios you can be reasonably sure you code is fine. Just treat it as black box. If all inputs give you expected outputs it doesn't matter how it happens.

Comment: "You can mock other dependency and check that no methods were called" this definitely solves my problem. Thank you very much. I didn't think of that.